# I Cannot Find my Android app on the Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
[2012-07-19 23:02:35 - dailymoney] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-07-19 23:02:35 - dailymoney] Uploading dailymoney.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-07-19 23:02:36 - dailymoney] Installing dailymoney.apk...
[2012-07-19 23:03:33 - dailymoney] Success!
[2012-07-19 23:03:33 - dailymoney] \dailymoney\bin\dailymoney.apk installed on device
[2012-07-19 23:03:33 - dailymoney] Done!
```

When I run in the emulator it opens fine but my app is not visibly listed anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Keep the mouse at the center button and drag the mouse upwards to see all the apps in the emulator

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing the launcher intent filter. One of the activities, need to be flagged as the launcher activity.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ccases

Look at your AndroidManifest.xml, and check if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

You must check the android min sdk in AndroidManifest.xml

add for example

> android:minSdkVersion = 10

if you have an

> android:targetSdkVersion big than android:minSdkVersion

you must remove it

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but just check what is your emulator SDK version and targetsdk version in your manifest. That was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be under in the application screen. Press the middle button in the home screen.